# Rails | I want to show only somes articles

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 tables :
-user_activity : that contains ID activities and ID user
-activity : contains Id, Id user etc ...

I want to display only the activities that are in the 2 tables

there is my code : 
-activities contain ALL the activities of the user
-usersactivities_id contain ALL the user_activity of the user in one tab (ex : 10 , 2 , 3)

```
  def fetch_maj_activities
    user = current_user
    activities = []
    user.groups.each do |group|
      activities << Activity.where(group: group)
    end


    usersactivities_id = current_user.user_activities.select('activity_id').map(&:activity_id).uniq

    activities.each do |activity|
      if usersactivities_id.include? activity.id
      else
        activities = activities.flatten.reject {|a| a.id == activity.id}
      end
    end
    @all_activities = activities.flatten.sort_by(&:updated_at).reverse
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

log :

```
  CACHE Activity Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."group_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["group_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
  ↳ /home/benjamin/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.0.rc1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
Did you mean?  ids):

app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:65:in `block in fetch_maj_activities'
app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:64:in `each'
app/controllers/activities_controller.rb:64:in `fetch_maj_activities'
```

Comment: can you explain more clearly what exactly you want to display?

Comment: what does this line do `if usersactivities_id.include? activity.id` ? does it throw you an error?

Comment: Humm sorry for my english :x 
I only want to display the activities in user_activities and activity (their link is the id of the user and the id of the news) https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/21/4/1527156071-capture-du-2018-05-24-12-00-46.png

Comment: @seethough it normally checks if the id of the activity is in useractivity I update the post to show you the log :)

Comment: Try `Activity.joins("INNER JOIN user_activities ON user_activities.activity_id = activities.id AND user_activities.user_id = ?", current_user.id).where(group: current_user.group_ids).order("updated_at DESC")` and play with order by changing `DESC` to `ASC`

Comment: By the way, where did you take that beautiful graph from?

Comment: http://db.lewagon.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is the Answer, working for me :)

```
  def fetch_maj_activities

    user = current_user
    activities = []
    usersactivities_id = current_user.user_activities.select('activity_id').map(&:activity_id).uniq

    user.groups.each do |group|
      activities << Activity.where(group: group)
    end



    usersactivities_id.each do |useractid|
      activities.flatten.each do |act|
        if act.id == useractid
          activities = activities.reject {|a|a}

        end
      end
    end

    @all_activities = activities.flatten.sort_by(&:updated_at).reverse
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {render :action => "fetch_activities"}
    end
  end
```